# Erro no site usando jquery

Tags: jquery

Eu sei que é simples, mas eu sou iniciante em jQuery.

Estou tentando criar um site de lista de tarefas, onde o usuário pode adicionar a tarefa e depois clicar na tarefa pra que ela fique riscada quando for concluída.

Mas meu código só muda a classe, quando tem um numero impar de itens - só os impares, e quando tem um numero par - só os pares

```
$('document').ready(() => {

  $('form').on('submit', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const novaTarefa = $('#nova-tarefa').val();
    const novoItem = $(`
      <li>
        <a id="tarefa" class="">
          ${novaTarefa}
        </a>
      </li>`
);

    $(novoItem).appendTo('ol div')

    $('#nova-tarefa').val('')

    $('li #tarefa').click(() => $(event.target).toggleClass('riscado'))

  })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema, achei aqui que eu deveria usar:

```
$('ol').on('click', 'li', () => $(event.target).toggleClass('riscado'))
```

fora do 'form' on submit, e excluir a função click que tinha anteriormente

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).